# ExpandableListView not pushing the UI under it when expands

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-xml, android-nestedscrollview

below is my XML code, I have multi expandable list view (5) each one with a different adapter, and all the views are inside the vertical scroll view.
but when clicking on the header of each expandable item it shows the items but not expands  ( it shows all items within the header first set height)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".screens.home.ui.dailyreportes.DailyReportsDetailsFragment">
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCompat3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/elv_work_logs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        >

    </ExpandableListView>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/elv_equipment_logs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/elv_work_logs"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        >

    </ExpandableListView>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/elv_material_delivery_logs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/elv_equipment_logs"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        >

    </ExpandableListView>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/elv_activity_logs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/elv_material_delivery_logs"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        >

    </ExpandableListView>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/elv_schedule_delays_logs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/elv_activity_logs"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        >

    </ExpandableListView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

for each child layout, I tried match_parent and wrap_content but got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

> Note : We cannot use the value wrap_content for the android:layout_height attribute of the ExpandableListView in XML unless the parent’s size is strictly specified

And also you won't need the scrollView as the ExpandableListView is scrollable by default.

You can refer [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial)

Comment: I'll take your note into consideration, for the scroll view, I have 5 expandable lists (lists not child of the same list) when expand all of them the last two views will not fit into the screen, while I can scroll the first 3 the last two will not even appear in the screen

Comment: @AhmedLaoun As the note says, you can't use wrap_content to the height variable and you also can't use match_parent because then each of your ExpandableListView would take up the whole screens height even in the collapsed state. You can try wrapping each of the ExpandableListView inside another View(like a LinearLayout) give the parent view a specified height and make your ExpandableListView's height as match_parent